# Argument of type 'typeof globalThis' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntryService'

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to pass my service to an instance of a class that I pass to a method decorator.

Here's the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class EntryService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(EntryEntity)
        private readonly entryRepository: Repository<EntryEntity>,
        @InjectRepository(ImageEntity)
        private readonly imageRepository: Repository<ImageEntity>,
        private readonly awsService: AwsService,
        private readonly connection: Connection,
        private readonly categoriesService: CategoriesService,
        private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
        private readonly usersService: UserService,
        private readonly imagesService: ImagesService,
        private readonly notificationService: NotificationsService,
    ) {}

    @RecordEntryOperation(new CreateOperation(this))
    public async create(createEntryDto: CreateEntryBodyDto): Promise<Entry> {
      const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
      await queryRunner.connect();
      await queryRunner.startTransaction();
      try {
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
        // more code
      } catch (err) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      } finally {
        await queryRunner.release();
      }
    }
}
```

The thing here is that I need to use EntryService inside that class I pass to the `RecordEntryOperation` decorator.

The decorator (not fully implemented yet):

```
export const RecordEntryOperation = (operation: Operation) => {
    return (target: object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        const original = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = async function(...args: any[]) {
            const response = await original.apply(this, args);
            console.log(`operation.execute()`, await operation.execute());
            return response;
        };
    };
};
```

The `CreateOperation` class looks like this (not fully implemented yet):

```
export class CreateOperation extends Operation {
    constructor(public entryService: EntryService) { super(); }

    public async execute(): Promise<any> {
        return this.entryService.someEntryServiceOperation();
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting reads as follows:

```
Argument of type 'typeof globalThis' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntryService'.
  Type 'typeof globalThis' is missing the following properties from type 'EntryService': entryRepository, imageRepository, awsService, and 53 more.
```

I don't fully understand what this error is about. I suspect that it means that the `this` passed to the `CreateOperation` class does not have all these dependencies injected into the service by the dependency injector.

I tried different things, but to no avail. Seems like I don't completely understand what is going on.

Any ideas?

What would be the right way to structure the code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
@RecordEntryOperation(new CreateOperation(this))
```

`this` does not refer to the instance of `EntryService` as you might expect, instead it refers to the `globalThis` (that `this` actually refers to the current module), thus the error. What you could do is to change your `Operation`-class a bit and pass the `entryService` to the execute method.

```
export class CreateOperation extends Operation {
    constructor() { super(); }

    public async execute(entryService: EntryService): Promise<any> {
        return entryService.someEntryServiceOperation();
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following in your decorator:

```
export const RecordEntryOperation = (OperationType: typeof CreateOperation) => {
    return (target: object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {      
        const operation = new OperationType(); 
        const original = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = async function(...args: any[]) {
            const response = await original.apply(this, args);
            console.log(`operation.execute()`, await operation.execute(this));
            return response;
        };
    };
};
```

Then use it with:

```
@RecordEntryOperation(CreateOperation)
public async create(createEntryDto: CreateEntryBodyDto): Promise<Entry> { .. }
```

Comment: Had a little bug, pls reload and take the newest version :)

Comment: Tried running this code, everything seems to look smooth, but `this.entryService` inside the `RecordEntryOperation` is `undefined` for some reason.

Comment: Oh it should actually be just `this` as `this` *is* the `EntryService`, right? See my edit.

Comment: Aaah yeah, right, I didn't notice it, now it seems to work as expected! Thanks.